# Can't print an element doing a map (REACT

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, printing, jsx

im trying to do a .map of an array I have, just to print the content.
I write console.log with the info I need, and it works, but when I have to print it, it dont' works.

Thanks all.

```
const [article, setArticle] = useState([])


useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(link).then((element) => {
        let data = element.data.map(element => element)
        let allArticles = [];
        allArticles.push(data)

        setArticle(allArticles.flat())  
        }        
    )

}, [])

let text = article.map( (element,i) =>{
    //console.log(i,element.feed)  --> this works 
    <p>{element.feed} </p> // this not
})

return text;
```

Comment: Typo?  You forgot to `return` from the callback function for `.map()`...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Im junior, sometimes I forgot easy things and waste lot of hours.... !!
Thanks for asnwer, now it works x)

Answer (score 0):

you should add the return like this:

```
let text = article.map( (element,i) =>{
    //console.log(i,element.feed)  --> this works 
    return <p>{element.feed} </p>
})
```

and if you don't want the `console.log` remember that you can return it directly like this:

```
let text = article.map( (element,i) => <p>{element.feed} </p>)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wrote ' { ' when it wasnt necessary... Im learning and I see that sometimes I waste tons of hours in little thins.
THanks again!!